# extracting data from a domain ncfile

Tags: python, coordinates, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I am trying to extract data from each grid cell in a user-specified (non rectangular) domain defined by lat / lon boundaries.  My input file is on a curvilinear grid.  I have tried various methods python ,cdo, ncks, but I still cannot figure it out.  I just want a timeseries of information for each grid cell in my polygon domain subset of the input ncfile.  My input ncfile information is given here:

```
$ ncdump -h 1979_sfc_out.nc 

netcdf \1979_sfc_out {
dimensions:
    x = 83 ;
    y = 94 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (8736 currently)
    nv4 = 4 ;
variables:
    float time(time) ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "hours since 1979-1-2 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "standard" ;
    float x(x) ;
        x:axis = "x" ;
        x:long_name = "X-coordinate in Cartesian system" ;
        x:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
        x:units = "meters" ;
    float y(y) ;
        y:axis = "y" ;
        y:long_name = "Y-coordinate in Cartesian system" ;
        y:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
        y:units = "meters" ;
    float lon(y, x) ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:valid_range = -180., 180. ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:bounds = "lon_bnds" ;
    float lat(y, x) ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:valid_range = -90., 90. ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:bounds = "lat_bnds" ;
    float lon_bnds(y, x, nv4) ;
        lon_bnds:units = "degreesE" ;
    float lat_bnds(y, x, nv4) ;
        lat_bnds:units = "degreesN" ;
    char mapping ;
        mapping:false_easting = 0. ;
        mapping:false_northing = 0. ;
        mapping:grid_mapping_name = "polar_stereographic" ;
        mapping:latitude_of_projection_origin = 90. ;
        mapping:standard_parallel = 64. ;
        mapping:straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole = -152. ;
        mapping:semi_major_axis = 6370000. ;
        mapping:semi_minor_axis = 6370000. ;
    float SEAICE(time, y, x) ;
        SEAICE:_FillValue = -9999.f ;
        SEAICE:units = "fraction" ;
        SEAICE:long_name = "Ice concentration (ice=1;no ice=0)" ;
        SEAICE:grid_mapping = "mapping" ;
        SEAICE:coordinates = "lon lat" ;
```

Some of the things I have tried are

```
lat1=71.2
lat2=72.9
lon1=-176.5
lon2=-160

cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 $ifile $box1_ofile
cdo sellonlatbox (Abort): Float parameter >lon1< contains invalid character at position 1!
```

I think the problem is my input file has the x,y dimension in meters (which does not have a negative sign and likely is the 'invalid character at position 1'), and I am asking cdo to extract the lat/lon dimension in degrees.  I have the variable 'mapping' in my ncfile which might be useful to convert meters to lat/lon, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

And ncks doesn't work for me here, likely due to the same meter <-> lon/lat problem I am seeing with cdo.

```
ncks -v SEAICE,U10,V10 -d latitude,71.2,72.9 -d longitude,-176.5,-160. $ifile -O $box1_ofile

ncks: ERROR dimension latitude is not in input file
```

Although I want a polygon extracted, these examples I have tried are just rectangle subsets, which I thought to get the polygon I can do multiple rectangle subsets to achieve my final polygon shape, but if there is a better way to do this any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCO's auxiliary coordinates [feature](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#aux) are designed to hyperslab  curvilinear coordinates on an unstructured grid with 1-D lat and lon. Try this:

```
ncks -X lon_min,lon_max,lat_min,lat_max in.nc out.nc
ncks -X -176.5,-160.,71.2,72.9 in.nc out.nc
```

You may also daisy-chain multiple -X options to get weird polygons. Unfortunately that probably won't work for you because, I just noticed, you have a curvilinear grid with 2D lat and lon. For that try the ncap2 where [feature](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#where). The examples in the manual show how to mask along rectangular boundaries, and you can daisy chain the conditions in the where() statement to obtain a polygon. This will not change the dimensionality of the output file, but it allows you to set everything outside the polygon to a _FillValue.